# Gauss-Jordan using stacks and list

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, linear-algebra, lists, stacks

I have a homework assignment in which I need to write an implementation of Gauss-Jordan with complete pivoting.  Complete pivoting is a modification to the basic Gauss-Jordan algorithm in which rows and columns are swapped around pivots.  This is done to minimize the numerical errors by avoiding operations with small floating-point values.

A common approach would be to use `for` loops for swapping rows, but it would cost $O(n)$ operations to move a row and $O(n)$ to move a column. Using stack and list could be faster.

So the question is, how can stacks and lists be used in an implementation of Gauss-Jordan to efficiently swap columns in a matrix $A$?

I can change rows using pointers, but I can't realize how to use those structures to move columns and do Gauss-Jordan.

EDIT: Sorry i was to tired when create this question, as i'm not from a english speaker native country, i made some mistakes. The questions is about swapping columns using lists and stack. I'm really sorry, i wasted almost week thinking about it.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is called **indirection**. Instead of physically moving the rows/columns, you move their names.

Let's say I call row 1 `r[0]`, and row 3 `r[2]`, in a matrix A, which has size n  by n. Initially, the rows are exactly as I call them, so we initialize `r[i] = i` for all `i < n`.

Now I want to swap the third (`r[2]`) and the fifth row (`r[4]`). I could move the elements in matrix A, but this would require *n* swaps. Instead, I can just swap `r[2]` and `r[4]`! This is just swapping one integer.

The tradeoff is that now we must read matrix A as `A[r[i]][c[j]]` (where `c` is the equivalent of `r`, but for columns) instead of `A[i][j]`. This is a bit slower.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with orlp's answer, which correctly discusses the complete pivoting asked about in the question.  This answer shows a common variant, partial pivoting, which only swaps rows (and not columns).  This approach is often more efficient, but complete pivoting can offer more reliable results.

#### The problem

The mathematical method that you're referring to, i.e. pivoting in Gauss-Jordan elimination, requires swapping rows in a matrix.

Naively, rows can be swapped by swapping each of their values one-at-a-time:

```
// Swap rows 1 and 3
int row_0 = 1;
int row_1 = 3;

for (int i=0; i < rowLength; ++i)
{
    var temp = matrix[row_0, i];
    matrix[row_0, i] = matrix[row_1, i];
    matrix[row_1, i] = temp;
}
```

This gets you from

```
matrix[,] = {  1    2    3    4
               5    6    7    8
               9   10   11   12
              13   14   15   16  }
```

to

```
matrix[,] = {  1    2    3    4
              13   14   15   16 
               9   10   11   12
               5    6    7    8 }
```

But, as you've said, that requires looping over each element in the rows to swap them, and you want something more efficient.

#### The solution:  Indirection

Instead of using a multi-dimensional array like `matrix[,]`, you can use an array-of-arrays (also called a [jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array)) like `matrix[][]`.

```
row_0[] =   {  1    2    3    4  }
row_1[] =   {  5    6    7    8  }
row_2[] =   {  9   10   11   12  }
row_3[] =   { 13   14   15   16  }

matrix[] =  {        row_0
                     row_1
                     row_2
                     row_3       }
```

You can still access the array in pretty much the same manner as before; the notation just changes slightly:

```
//  Before, with multi-dimensional array:
matrix[2, 3]  == 7

//  After, with array-of-arrays:
matrix[2][3]  == 7
```

However swapping rows is a lot easier since you have an array that's literally just a collection of row indices.  By swapping those row indices, you effectively swap those rows.

```
// Swap rows 1 and 3
int row_0 = 1;
int row_1 = 3;

var temp = matrix[row_0];
matrix[row_0] = matrix[row_1];
matrix[row_1] = temp;
```

This gives you the same switch without having to loop over each element in the row.

```
row_0[] =   {  1    2    3    4  }
row_1[] =   {  5    6    7    8  }
row_2[] =   {  9   10   11   12  }
row_3[] =   { 13   14   15   16  }

matrix[] =  {        row_0
                     row_3
                     row_2
                     row_1       }
```

#### Performance

This change from a multi-dimensional array to array-of-arrays has a few effects on performance and implementation:

- Memory allocation:

  - Multi-dimensional arrays are often allocated as one block of memory.
  - Array-of-arrays can allocate $1$ block of memory for the array-of-arrays, then $n_{\text{rows}}$ for each subordinate array, for a total of $n_{\text{rows}}+1$ memory blocks.
- Row-swap operations:

  - Multi-dimensional arrays can't just swap rows; the operation must be performed member-wise.
  - Array-of-arrays can swap rows, as shown above.
- Serialization, caching, and multi-threading:

  - If your matrix is huge, you might only need to work with part of it at a time, or part of it in different threads.  An array-of-arrays allows you to access the relevant parts without serializing/loading/passing the entire thing.

A few bloggers have noted that arrays-of-arrays can be more performant in C#.  This can be counter-intuitive as they're more general structures than multi-dimensional arrays, but apparently real-world implementations can have arrays-of-arrays be faster even when their extra functionality isn't used.

Comment: The "array of arrays" method won't allow you to efficiently swap columns though, which my method of explicit indirection does.

Comment: @orlp Good point; fixed the description.  Dunno how I got my wires crossed on that one.